# Unable to capture Behave logging events in a memory buffer for later display or query

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, bdd, python-behave

I am trying to capture the logging in behave tests. The behave version I am using is 1.2.5. The documentation can be found here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-behave/stable/python-behave.pdf
Unfortunately, I am not able to get the contents of the "buffer" attribute  populated when instantiating an object from "class behave.log_capture.LoggingCapture(config, level=None)"

This the kind of layout I have for my current BDD:
environment.py

```
import behave
from behave import log_capture
from behave.log_capture import *

def before_all(context):
    context.config.setup_logging()
    context.config.log_capture = True
    context.logging_level = "INFO"

    # create the LoggingCapture object.
    context.log_capture_data = log_capture.LoggingCapture(context.config)

    #... rest of the code here.

# @capture
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    #... rest of the code here

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    #... rest of the code here

def after_all(context):
    #... rest of the code here.
```

list_of_scenarios.feature

```
#... list of the scenarios.

# In one of the scenarios I need to access the "buffer" attribute which contains the captured data:
print("buffer contains {}".format(context.log_capture_data.buffer))
```

list_of_scenarios.py

```
#... implementation of steps for the scenarios
```

What am I missing? When I try to see the contents of the attribute "buffer" using `print("buffer contains {}".format(context.log_capture_data.buffer))`
I get an empty list: `buffer contains []`

I do see the "INFO:...." logging on the console. I believe this is captured on the "stdout". I am trying to get the same output on the attribute "buffer".

Please note: I have setup the behave in Linux. And I execute from the command line using command: behave test_setup. test_setup is a directory that houses environment.py, features and the implementation of steps files.

Thank you.